# Understanding the Cube display in SQL Studio Manager

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have built a small data warehouse using the Adventure works database.  I have deployed it to SQL Studio Manager.  I have written my first MDX query

```
select 
customer.[full name].members on rows,
order (measures.[sales amount],asc) on columns
from [Adventure Works DW2012]
```

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

I understand that the top level of the hierarchy are dimensions i.e. Customer, Date, Due Date, Interne Sales, Order Date, Product and Ship Date.  I understand that dimensions have attributes.  For example: Model Name, Product Line, Product Name are attributes of the Product dimension and Product Model Lines is a hierarchy of the Product dimension.

What is meant by: Financial; History and Stocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've come up against something I think is a genuinely confusing and ill-designed aspect of SSAS.

You're correct that Model Name, Product Line and Product Name are attributes of the Product dimension.  But what you're seeing here (in your screenshot) is *hierarchies* called Model Name, Product Line and Product Name.

These are not "hierarchies" in the sense that most people use the term (a structure with more than one level).  They're the "attribute hierarchies" based on the attributes of the same name.  They only have <del>one level</del> two levels.  (**EDIT:** as whytheq pointed out, they have one leaf level, and almost always also have an "All" level).

**(EDIT)** Product Model Lines is a "real" (aka "user") hierarchy, with multiple levels apart from the All and leaf levels, based on multiple attributes.

Financial, History and Stocking are "folders".  They get "created" by the setting of any AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder property of any Attribute in the Dimension design (or the DisplayFolder property of any "real" hierarchy).  They have nothing to do with any dimension structure - they're just for display convenience.  Probably necessary because, as becomes clearer the more I try to explain it, the structure of Dimensions in SSAS is really unnecessarily complicated.

You can hide the "attribute hierarchies" from client applications (e.g. Excel) by setting the AttributeHierarchyVisible property of the attribute to False.  But they'll still show up in the MDX "helper" screen you're looking at.

Comment: attribute hierarchies have 2 levels

Comment: Do you mean "All" and the leaf level?  If so, of course you're right.  But IMHO that still makes the term "hierarchy" a misleading one for attribute hierarchies.

Comment: All and leaf level is exactly what I mean. Agreed there are lots of aspects within olap that are unusual and possibly misleading

Comment: Attribute hierarchies can be hidden - but they are often useful. Personally I'd leave them visible unless a definite case to hide them. Also maybe worth mentioning the phrase `Measure Group` as I think this is connected to the folders you mention? p.s. nice answer (upped)

Comment: Thanks, I have asked another question here if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112592/is-power-pivot-multi-dimensional

Comment: I do not understand why these hierarchies are named: Financial; history and stocking? Why is this?

Comment: @w0051977: They're not hierarchies, but folders in which to display hierarchies. They have nothing to do with the dimension structure or the name of any object in it.  You could rename them to Stan, Kyle and Cartman if you wanted, by changing the DisplayFolder properties of attributes in the dimensions.